# Write a recursive function in IJVM

Tags: recursion

I am currently writing an ijvm program for solving Hanoi Tower recursively. I am not sure how should I set the number for Object reference for the method called within the method.

This is the java code which I use to "translate" to the ijvm code:

```
public class Tower{
  public static void towers(int n, int i, int j) {
    int k;
    if (n == 1) { 
      System.out.println("Move a disk from " + i + " to " + j);
    } else {
      k = 6 - i - j;
      towers(n - 1, i, k); 
      towers(1, i, j); 
      towers(n - 1, k, j); 
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    towers(5,1,3);
  }
}
```

This is the ijvm code:

```
 ;BIPUSH 0 is for the object reference
 BIPUSH 0
 BIPUSH 5
 BIPUSH 1
 BIPUSH 3
 INVOKEVIRTUAL tower
 HALT

 ;the recursive method
 tower 4 1
 ILOAD 1
 BIPUSH 1
 IF_ICMPEQ L1
 BIPUSH 6   
 ILOAD 2
 ISUB    
 ILOAD 3
 ISUB
 ISTORE 4

 ;this is for the method towers(n - 1, i, k); 
 ;BIPUSH 1 is for the object reference
 BIPUSH 1
 ILOAD 1
 BIPUSH 1
 ISUB
 ILOAD 2
 ILOAD 4
 INVOKEVIRTUAL tower

 ;this is for the method towers(1, i, j); 
 ;BIPUSH 2 is for the object reference
 BIPUSH 2  
 BIPUSH 1
 ILOAD 2
 ILOAD 3
 INVOKEVIRTUAL tower

 ;this is for the method towers(n-1, k, j); 
 ;BIPUSH 3 is for the object reference
 BIPUSH 3
 ILOAD 1
 BIPUSH 1
 ISUB
 ILOAD 4
 ILOAD 3
 INVOKEVIRTUAL tower

 L1:  ILOAD 3
 ILOAD 2
 SPRINT "Move a disk from "
 IPRINT
 SPRINT " to "
 IPRINT
 SPRINT "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The object reference is just a place holder, since the IJVM does not implement object orientation. You can place any value there. It will be overwritten, but never read, in the INVOKEVIRTUAL routine.